# Predicted y during training by linear regression

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm doing a linear regression:

```
lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("R2 OLS: " + str(lr.score(X_train, y_train)))
```

It is easy to get the predicted values for testing:

```
lr.predict(X_test)
```

and then I can further use those values.
But is there any way to get the predicted values (y) by the OLS during **training**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can predict on the X_train:

```
lr.predit(X_train)
```

For example, this is where the regression line is:

[image]